# SerialPort ReadTimeout is 5 seconds, but the timeout takes 432 seconds

Tags: c#, exception, blocking

I have a bit of code that is looking for a byte on a serial port, and am trying to test what happens when no data comes across.

```
byte[] startByteArray = new byte[1];

// Find a start byte
try
{
    do
    {
        Logger.trace("Starting read at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Logger.trace("comm.ReadTimeout = " + comm.ReadTimeout);
        comm.Read(startByteArray, 0, 1);
        Logger.trace("Found a byte: " + startByteArray[0].ToString("X2"));

        if((new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - startTime)).TotalMilliseconds > comm.ReadTimeout)
            throw new TimeoutException("Invalid Data: Start byte never found, but others were: " + startByteArray[0].ToString("X2"));

    } while (!isStartByte(startByteArray[0]));

}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    Logger.trace("Caught exception at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Logger.trace("comm.ReadTimeout = " + comm.ReadTimeout);
    Logger.trace("Exception = " + ex.Message);

    if(ex.Message.Contains("Invalid Data"))
        driverEvent = new DriverEvent(DriverEventCode.INVALID_DATA, ex.Message, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
    else
        driverEvent = new DriverEvent(DriverEventCode.NO_DATA, "No bytes received in " + comm.ReadTimeout + " milliseconds: " + ex.Message, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
    return null;
}
```

Some of the output generated is as follows:

```
03.24 16:04:22 TRACE:COM301.295           Starting read at 3/24/2014 4:04:22 PM
03.24 16:04:22 TRACE:COM301.295           comm.ReadTimeout = 5000
03.24 16:11:34 TRACE:COM301.295           Caught exception at 3/24/2014 4:11:34 PM
03.24 16:11:34 TRACE:COM301.295           comm.ReadTimeout = 5000
03.24 16:11:34 TRACE:COM301.295           Exception = The operation has timed out.
03.24 16:11:34 ERROR:COM301.280           NO_DATA error received: No bytes received in 5000 milliseconds: The operation has timed out. was generated.
...
03.24 16:12:11 TRACE:COM301.287           Starting read at 3/24/2014 4:12:11 PM
03.24 16:12:11 TRACE:COM301.287           comm.ReadTimeout = 5000
03.24 16:19:23 TRACE:COM301.287           Caught exception at 3/24/2014 4:19:23 PM
03.24 16:19:23 TRACE:COM301.287           comm.ReadTimeout = 5000
...
03.24 16:20:00 TRACE:COM301.293           Starting read at 3/24/2014 4:20:00 PM
03.24 16:20:00 TRACE:COM301.293           comm.ReadTimeout = 5000
03.24 16:27:13 TRACE:COM301.293           Caught exception at 3/24/2014 4:27:13 PM
03.24 16:27:13 TRACE:COM301.293           comm.ReadTimeout = 5000
```

The ReadTimeout is set for 5000 milliseconds; why would it be taking over 7 minutes?  I can't think of another thread that would be holding the serial port hostage.

**UPDATE**

All the control lines are being held high; could the SerialPort class be disregarding the ReadTimeout because of this?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Duly noted, good sir.

Comment: `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` is ridiculously bad.  It would be well worth seeing whether you have the same problem when using the Win32 API directly on the same hardware.  You can use C# and p/invoke, or C++, or bindings in any number of dynamic languages like python.  Just try doing the same operation with no `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`.

Comment: The lead developer made a class that derives from the SerialPort class, so I think we might be stuck with it for the time being...

Comment: @mattnificent: I didn't say to tear it out yet.  I suggested to write a small piece of code not using it to test this timeout problem.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  We're doing this on a virtual COM port created by some 3rd party for their hardware, so I wonder if there could be compatibility issues with the layer below us.

Comment: Timeout implementation is a driver detail.  USB drivers are notorious.  Try another one.